# Pass multiple bash arrays to Python using argparse

Tags: python, bash, argparse

I have a Python script that I want to run from a bash, and it needs multiple string arrays/lists inputs. This answer by [lorenzog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33867675/7032387) in another question explains how to do it with one array, and it works fine. But how can I pass multiple arrays? Here's what I've tried so far:

**Bash script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a first=("one" "two" "three")
declare -a second=("four" "five")
declare -a third=("six")
declare -a fourth=("seven" "eight")

python argsprob.py "${first[@]}" "${second[@]}" "${third[@]}" "${fourth[@]}"
```

**Python script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('first', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('second', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('third', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('fourth', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.first)
print(args.second)
print(args.third)
print(args.fourth)
```

**Output**

```
$ bash argsprob.sh
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
['six']
['seven']
['eight']
```

**Desired output**

```
['one','two','three']
['four','five']
['six']
['seven','eight']
```

As you can probably tell I have no idea what I'm doing. I've tried other ways of using **argparse** (more arguments, different "nargs", etc) but none of them works. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look at `sys.argv`.  I think your bash command expands the arrays in to one long list of strings.  So `argparse` has no idea of where your original  `first` ends and `second` begins.  It allocates one string each for the last 3 arguments (because of their '+'), and allocates the rest to the first.

Comment: Change the `nargs` to 3,2,1,2 respectively.

Comment: Another option is to make the arguments flagged (`optionals`).  Then the flags ('--first', etc) act as delimiters between the arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Chaginc nargs to 3,2,1,2 worked, but this makes things harder when I don't know how many elements the lists have. Second method you said worked perfectly! Thank you! If you answer I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
import argparse
import sys
print(sys.argv[1:])
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--first', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('--second', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('--third', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('--fourth', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

the call:

```
1948:~/mypy$ python stack49282913.py --first "${first[@]}" --second "${second[@]}" --th "${third[@]}" --fo "${fourth[@]}"

['--first', 'one', 'two', 'three', '--second', 'four', 'five', '--th', 'six', '--fo', 'seven', 'eight']

Namespace(first=['one', 'two', 'three'], fourth=['seven', 'eight'], second=['four', 'five'], third=['six'])
```